# Cannot convert value of type 'Image' to expected argument type 'String' in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have Menu button, and it has system image envelope.fill

```
 MenuButton(name: "Catalogue", image:"envelope.fill", selectedMenu: 
 $menuData.selectedMenu,animation: 
  animation)
```

but when change for custom image, it throw error as "Cannot convert value of type 'Image' to expected argument type " And idea?

```
  MenuButton(name: "Catalogue", Image("custom-image"), selectedMenu: 
 $menuData.selectedMenu,animation: animation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have the parameter `image` missing from the second call. It should look like the way the MenuButton parameters are set.

```
MenuButton(name: "Catalogue",
           image: Image("custom-image"),
           selectedMenu: $menuData.selectedMenu,
           animation: animation)
```

So your menu button declaration should be like this:

```
MenuButton(name: String,
           image: Image,
           selectedMenu: MenuData,
           animation: Animation)
```

Comment: tnx so much, but still say "Cannot convert value of type 'Image' to expected argument type 'String'"

Comment: It is because you have to swap your `image` parameter to accept an `Image` instead of a `String`. Look at the second part of code I shared to you. Can you update your question with the 'MenuButton' declaration if you are still stuck?